# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

I am trying to integrate `Firebase` into my app and I follow in the instructions from Google. However as soon as I sync my gradle file I have the following error message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task :app:processDebugResources'.
Error: more than one library with package name com.google.android.gms
```

If I remove the line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` then it works fine again :(

Can you you guys help me find out where the problem is?

Belo is my app grade file.

Thanks in advance

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.biggift'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("android.keystore")
            storePassword "123456"
            keyAlias "sensiblewallet"
            keyPassword "123456"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            //multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {

//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile files('libs/NativeXMonetizationSDK_v5.4.12.jar')
compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.8.jar')
compile files('libs/SuperRewards-3.1b.jar')
compile files('libs/TrialpayAndroidSdk.jar')
compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
compile files('libs/adcolony.jar')
compile files('libs/adscendmedia1.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
compile files('libs/mediationsdk-6.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/personasdk1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/tapjoyconnectlibrary.jar')
compile files('libs/vungle-publisher-adaptive-id-3.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/chartboost.jar')
compile files('libs/applovin-sdk-6.1.5.jar')
compile files('libs/heyzap.jar')
compile files('libs/revmob.jar')
compile project(':appGradeLib')
//compile project(':sensiblefacebooksdk')
compile project(':googleplayserviceslib')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile files('libs/AdxmiCustomizedSdk_v1.2.0_2015-11-13.jar')
compile files('libs/AdxmiSdk_v5.4.0_2015-11-12.jar')
compile project(':unity-ads')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: From @SergJ4: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40155490 It helped me. I've just added compile dependency for play-services of the same version as firebase and synced project.

Answer (score 0):

The google_play_services_lib already uses the google play services.jar file. Check the lib folder in that project. That is causing the duplicity. You need to keep the library on either one of the 2 places, that is in you library project or here.