# processDebugResources'. > Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I added Firebase Cloud Messaging to my Android app and I'm upgrading my old app from GCM to FCM. I tried the sample app by following the steps in [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com), which works fine.

After embedding same code into the existing code in my app, even though the build is successful, while trying to run the app on a device in Android Studio, I get this error:

```
getting the error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'.
```

See the dependencies screenshot taken from terminal. I checked the dependencies using

```
command >gradlew -q dependencies project name:dependencies --configuratio
n compile
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Update your question with relevant info

Comment: are you sure that you included all the dependencies in the screenshot ?
from the error you are receiving it seems that you other dependencies that are not shown in the screenshot

Comment: After adding google play services with same version

Answer (score 0):

Previously some modules in my app was using old jar files of googleplayservices.

After using google play services with same version
like below

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
}
```

I hope it will help some one needed.